# Convert a percent value and use it as a number (for eg: 75.8% into 75.8) using angular/typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a value(for eg "75.8%") which is a string from am api and i want to use it as number so i can apply conditions

like this

```
<div 
   class="container" 
   [ngClass]="{
      'pos' : value > 0,
      'neg' : value < 0
   }"
   *ngIf="value"
>
   <span class="me-1">
      {{value}} % 
   </span>
                  
 </div>
```

Note:

Basically what i am doing is changing the background color to green (using class 'pos') if value is positive
and to red if value is negative

I tried without converting the percent value as i dont know how to convert it

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem you can convert the `value` to `float` by using `parseFloat(value)`. It will automatically ignore the `%`.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Example:

```js
const value = '74.4%';
console.log(parseFloat(value));
```